# useEffect has a missing dependency(when using useContext instead of useState)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from firestore, and I need to do it once, when page loads. Everything was OK when I was using useState:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=> {
  db.collection("articles").orderBy("date", "desc").get()
    .then(snapshot => {
  const tempArticles = [];
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => tempArticles.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
  setData(tempArticles)
})
}, [])
```

No warnings, everything was doing what it supposed to do.
Now I want to access data globally so I am using useContext instead of useState:

```
const {data, setData} = useContext(ArticleContext);

useEffect(()=> {
  db.collection("articles").orderBy("date", "desc").get()
    .then(snapshot => {
  const tempArticles = [];
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => tempArticles.push({...doc.data(), id: doc.id}))
  setData(tempArticles)
})
}, [])
```

And now I have warning

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setData'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: I don't think the useContext hook provides a 'setData' as a return.  I'd re-read the documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: If you are sure that `setData` doesn't change during component's lifecycle than you can add it to dependency array and still get `componentDidMount` behaviour. Ignore this warning otherwise